# Explanations and clarifications on wrapfig package

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig

After several lectures on the [`wrapfig`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgUKi.png) package (pag. 1 ad 2) and in this [guide](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/LaTeXpedia.pdf) (pag. 147), yet I don't understand how to use it correctly this package well for the creation of my book. In fact after many attempts I am able to insert an image in the correct position after numerous compilations in the desired place.

I have not understood how should I use `[<number of narrow lines>]`, i.e. how I must choose the exact number of these narrow lines (red rectangle).

[image]

In some situations of my book I have little text (words) and the figure invades either a definition or a theorem or an example. I simply ask you for a simple explanation how to use correctly the parameters of `wrapfig`, **`wrapfloat` environment**, and the difference between `r` and `R`. Similarly for the `L`, `l`, `i`, `I`, `o`, `O`.

**Lastly, I would like to know if exist a command that have the same function as the line break in Office Word software.**

If the English language is not correct and not clear, please edit my question. Thank you.

Here a MWE of my problems with `wrapfig`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{microtype} 

\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,amssymb}
\def\vf{\varphi}
\newcommand\xyz{(x,y,z)}

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
% Definition box % added
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=red,
backgroundcolor=yellow,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=2pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt]{dBox}    

\newtheorem{definitionT}{Definizione}[section]
\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{dBox}\begin{definitionT}}{\end{definitionT}\end{dBox}}   


\begin{document}
\section{Campi vettoriali, scalari, radiali, centrali e conservativi}\index{Campi vettoriali, scalari, radiali, centrali e conservativi}

\begin{definition} Un campo \textbf{vettoriale} (tridimensionale) è una funzione $\overline F: D\to\mathbb{R}^3$  dove $D$ è un aperto di $\mathbb{R}^3$; 
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}
Un campo \textbf{scalare} (tridimensionale) è una funzione $\vf: D\to\mathbb{R}$, dove $D$ è aperto di $\mathbb{R}^3$.
\end{definition}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{L}{0.4\textwidth}
\vspace{-2cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Vettore posizione $\textbf{r}$.}
\label{fig:sidecap}
\end{wrapfigure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

La variabile indipendente in $\mathbb{R}^3$ si indica molto spesso con $\mathbf{r}=|P-O|$ oppure con  $\overline r$, il vettore che è il {\em raggio vettore} o {\em vettore posizione} dall'origine al punto considerato, $\overline r=\textbf{r}=x \widehat{\mathbf x}+y\widehat{\mathbf y}+z\widehat{\mathbf z}$, con $\widehat{\mathbf x}=\overline e_1$ versore dell'asse $x$. Analogamente per gli altri\footnote{Usiamo in questo contesto $r$ minuscolo invece di $R$ maiuscolo.}. Il modulo di $\overline r$ è indicato con $r$, si pone cioè $r:=|\overline r|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, distanza dall'origine del punto $(x,y,z)$. Il versore di $\overline r$ è quindi $\widehat{\mathbf r}=\overline r/r$. 

\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:** I would like to delete my question because I can not reproduce the problem with my fonts used. When I changed the fonts and packages (see my MWE) the result is different from what I have. I'm leaving everything as it is now.
I apologise to all the users, but I hope I've done everything I have possible.

Comment: I find it hard to believe you posted this question with no usable example

Comment: what is your question? You posted a large section of code that no one can use as it includes files and command definitions that we haven't got, and shown an image of the output with two large arrows drawn on it without any indication of what they are supposed to indicate.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are perfectly right but if the position of the figure is not correct all the following text becomes all asymmetrical and unreadable. The use of this package becomes difficult for me inside my source.

Comment: How can anyone know what is the correct position? You have not said what you want to change and not provided any code that allows anyone to reproduce the problem. I have voted to close this question as unclear.

Comment: for example you have `\vspace{-2cm}` so that will make the image overprint the previous 2cm of text, in general it will be impossible to get any reasonable layout with such a command in your source. If you need it in this particular case then there may be some bad combination that that avoids, but in that case **you need to provide an example of the problem**.

Comment: If I run the new example with a full texlive 2018 It produces `! LaTeX Error: File \`mtpro2.sty' not found.`, `! Undefined control sequence. l.40 ... è una funzione $\overline F: D\to\mathbb` and `! Package pdftex.def Error: File `displacement.pdf' not found` Please provide an example that demonstrates the problem and does not use unrelated packages or fonts and image files that are not provided.

Comment: Note the stackexchanege model is that unclear questions should be closed and then re-opened once edited, not that they should be left open until fixed.

Comment: you are specifying  `\begin{wrapfigure}[7]` so only 7 lines are made short whatever size the figure, it is why the 10 line figure that you show overprints the last lines in the paragraph.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have changed my question with the sincere hope of being clearer. I have removed the code because before I ask a question I would like to better understand how this package works. Thank you very much to you and everyone and I apologize once again for the lack of clarity and the absence of connection.

Comment: your question isn't really clear at all now, and you deleted the example rather than clarifying it. The `[12]1 that you mark in red is optional an normally you should not supply it, but it is simply the number of lines that are made short, it's not clear what answer you could expect to your question on how to choose that, normally you do not need to specify  it at all.

Comment: I suppose it's better after the last edit  but now the only thing I see wrong in your image is that the image over-prints the preceding text which is the direct result of you adding `\vspace{-2cm}` and completely unrelated to `wrapfig`. If you don't intend to overprint the preceding 2cm, what do you intend `\vspace{-2cm}` to do?

Comment: Your question has an answer that has been voted twice, you can't delete it. To delete it, you must ask a moderator who alone will decide whether or not it should be deleted.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141367/why-cant-i-delete-my-own-question

Comment: @AndréC Kindest I'm leaving everything as it is now. I don't want to cause anybody any trouble. I can tell you that I put my heart into it to make everyone understand my request. I just can't, as I wrote, reproduce the code with the packages I am currently using. In chat I left some pictures. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last it depends on the text around the wrapfigure.  To show the effect I changed your given code to be more minimal (I used package `blindtext` to genaerate dummy text).

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\section{Campi vettoriali, scalari, radiali, centrali e conservativi}\index{Campi vettoriali, scalari, radiali, centrali e conservativi}

\blindtext

\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{L}{0.4\textwidth}
%\vspace{-2cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Vettore posizione $\textbf{r}$.}
\label{fig:sidecap}
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Please see that I commented your wrong `\vspace` inside wrapfigure. Please see that I need to reserve 12 lines as place for the inserted wrapfigure with image `example-image` from class `mwe` you need to have installed but you need not to have it loaded ...

The result is then:

[image]

So depending on your used image you have to play with the numbers of lines you have to reserve for the wrapfigure ...

Comment: why not simply delete the `[12]` and let wrapfig use the right number of lines for the supplied image automatically?

Comment: I have edit my question for clarifications of the `wrapfig` package :-(. Thank you very much to all users. I obviously really appreciated your response and everyone's comments.